# Double integral with variable boundaries in python Scipy + sympy (?)

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, integral

The full mathematical problem is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1318647/113873).

Briefly I want to integrate a function with a double integral. The inner integral has boundaries `20` and `x-2`, while the outer has boundaries `22` and `30`.

I know that with Scipy I can compute the double integral with `scipy.integrate.nquad`. I would like to do something like this:

```
def f(x, y):
    return (x ** 2 + y ** 2)
res = sp.integrate.nquad(f, [[22, 30], [20, x-2]])
```

Is it possible? Maybe using also `sympy`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I solved with `sympy`:

```
from sympy import *

x, y = symbols("x y")
f = (x ** 2 + y ** 2)
res = integrate(f, (y, 20, x-2), (x, 22, 30))
```

Basically `sympy.integrate` is able to deal with multiple integrations, also with variable boundaries.

Comment: Note that variables have to appear in the upper part of the range, not the lower. Something like `res = integrate(f, (y, 20, 22), (x, y, 30))` doesn't work. (It returns a function in `y`.)

Answer (score 6):

If you need the numerical integration and sympy is not an option. Then you could try something like the following.
For this example it seems quick, but I have a suspicion you may run into problems in general, see how well it does for your use case.Perhaps this possibly imperfect answer will prompt someone to submit something better.

I use the fact that we can do the integrations one after the other, integrating out the y first, to get a function of x, then integrating that.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

def integrand(x, y): 
    return (x ** 2 + y ** 2)

def y_integral(x):
    # Note scipy will pass args as the second argument
    # we can fiddle it to work correctly, but by symmetry we don't need to here.
    return quad(integrand, 20, x-2, args=(x))[0]
```

We then use this y_integral function as the result function of the inner integral.

```
res = quad(y_integral, 22, 30) 
print res
```

You could wrap this in a function if you use it regularly.