# Integrate custom function with sympy

Tags: python, function, sympy, integral

Is it possible to integrate custom function using sympy?

I want something like this:

```
def func(x, y):
    return something_with(x, y)

res = integrate(func, (y, x-2, 3), (x, 1, 2))
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You can subclass `Function`.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate some functions with [sympy's integrate](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/integrals/integrals.html). Suppose you had the function (one variable to make it simpler)

```
def my_func(x):
    return x**2 + x + 1
```

Then you could integrate it with

```
x = Symbol('x')
integrate(my_func(x), (x, a, b))
```

Although only limited mathematical functions are likely to work.

If you only care about the numerical answer, you could try [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html)'s `integrate.quad()` (or `scipy.integrate.dblquad()`) which will do numerical integration, and can tackle a broader set of functions within a small error.

```
scipy.integrate.quad(my_func, a, b)
```

Comment: Hi, is there any methods to tackle variable boundaries for the integral? Something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758933/double-integral-with-variable-boundaries-in-python-scipy-sympy

Comment: I assume you mean with scipy as with sympy this is covered in the question you linked, do you need numeric integration? I haven't come across a way to do this with numeric integration, but you could try turn it into an iterated integration, and using `integrate.quad()` twice, it may be slow however. I would recommend asking another question if you need numeric and variable bounds, or maybe specify some more information about your function

Comment: Oh that is your question! Didn't spot that.