# How to pass args() to integrate.quad in scipy?

Tags: python, lambda, scipy, parameter-passing

I was doing a numerical integration where instead of using

```
scipy.integrate.dblquad
```

I tried to build the double integral directly using

```
scipy.integrate.quad
```

From camz's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30786163/11141816

```
a=1
b=2

def integrand(theta, t): 
    return sin(t)*sin(theta);

def theta_integral(t):
    # Note scipy will pass args as the second argument
    return integrate.quad(integrand, b-a, t , args=(t))[0]

integrate.quad(theta_integral, b-a,b+a )
```

However, the part where it was confusing was how the args was passed through the function. For example, in the post `args=(t)` was pass through to the second argument `t` of the function integrand automatically, not the first argument `theta`, where in the scipy document https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html the only reference was

```
args: tuple, optional
    Extra arguments to pass to func.
```

and in fact their arguments had a comma `,` to be `args=(1,)`, instead of  `args=(1)` directly.

What if I decide to pass several variables, i.e.

```
def integrand(theta, t,a,b): 
    return sin(t)*sin(theta)*a*b;
```

how would I know which `args(t,a,b)` or `args(t,a,b,)` were the correct `args()` for the function?

How to pass `args()` to integrate.quad in scipy?

Comment: `args` is supposed to be a tuple, `args=(t,)`.  It may help to add a debugging `print(t, a, b)` to the function to get a clearer idea of what arguments `quad` passes.  Get a clear idea of what's happening with a single `quad` call before moving on the the nested case.

Comment: @hpaulj It seemed that it's just passing the elements of the tuple one by one. But on the official website it's not clear how the code (probably a loop) was written to pass the arguments or in which order.

Comment: The function call looks like `func(x, *args)`.  So if `args=(a,b,c)` this would the same as doing `func(x0,a,b,c)` (where `x0` is the initial value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [214]: from scipy.integrate import quad
```

A simple example.  I'm not using the `args`, just showing them:

```
In [215]: def foo(x,a,b,c):
     ...:     print(x,a,b,c)
     ...:     return x**2
     ...:     

In [216]: quad(foo, 0, 1, (1,(1,2,3),np.arange(2)))
0.5 1 (1, 2, 3) [0 1]
0.013046735741414128 1 (1, 2, 3) [0 1]
0.9869532642585859 1 (1, 2, 3) [0 1]
0.06746831665550773 1 (1, 2, 3) [0 1]
0.9325316833444923 1 (1, 2, 3) [0 1]
0.16029521585048778 1 (1, 2, 3) [0 1]
0.8397047841495122 1 (1, 2, 3) [0 1]
 ...
0.35280356864926987 1 (1, 2, 3) [0 1]
0.6471964313507301 1 (1, 2, 3) [0 1]
Out[216]: (0.33333333333333337, 3.700743415417189e-15)
```

That's all there is to `args`.

Looking at the code for `quad`, the first line is

```
if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    args = (args,)
```

So if you use `args=(t)`, that will be changed to `args=(t,)`.  Remember, in  python `(2)` is the same as `2`; the () just group operations in complex cases, otherwise they are ignored.  But `(1,)` is a tuple, as `(1,2)`.  It's really the comma that defines the tuple.

With your inner function, and an added print:

```
In [232]: def integrand(theta, t): 
     ...:     print(theta, t)
     ...:     return np.sin(t)*np.sin(theta)
     ...:     

In [233]: integrand(1,2)     # pass 2 numbers 
1 2
Out[233]: 0.7651474012342926

In [234]: integrand(1,np.arange(3))   # is still works if the 2nd is an array:

1 [0 1 2]
Out[234]: array([0.        , 0.70807342, 0.7651474 ])
```

`t` is an array, and so is `np.sin(t)`, and also the return. But you aren't passing arrays.  Calling it via quad, the `theta` varies, the `t` does not:

```
In [235]: quad(integrand, 0, 1, args=(1,))
0.5 1
0.013046735741414128 1
0.9869532642585859 1
...
0.6471964313507301 1
Out[235]: (0.38682227139505565, 4.2945899214059184e-15)

In [236]: quad(integrand, 0, 1, args=(1,2))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
TypeError: integrand() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The actual error is raised in compiled code, so isn't quite as transparent, but the effect the same as if I tried to pass 3 arguments:

```
In [237]: integrand(1,1,2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [237], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 integrand(1,1,2)

TypeError: integrand() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```